# Smallest integer verifying a property

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing for a test and i find this good exercice.

Can you please help me to answer the question d) of the following problem:
for the question a) the answer is 32

and for the question c) $f$ factors as the product of two linear polynomials , a quadratic and a fourth degree polynomial .

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: any idea please?